# How to make an HTTP request in Java and ignore the body

Tags: java

To be more specific, I mean specifically to just consume the HTTP headers over the network and stop the communication before the client receives the response body.

Example

Client makes a request

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (Java/1.8.0_262)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

Then the response over the network is just

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2020 22:41:21 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800
Content-Language: en
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Age: 1865
grace: none
Content-Length: 9213
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: More context?  Which side are you trying to implement?  Are you using Apache or some other web server?  Are you using a framework?

Comment: Does the server allow the HTTP `HEAD` method? More information can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

Comment: The server does not allow `HEAD`

Answer (score 1):

Http protocol has six method, one of the methods is 'HEAD'. You can try use HEAD method instead of GET method.

And another stupid way : declare a web interface, and return null string.Like this:

```
// a web interface
String result = "";
return result;
```

Comment: Try the second method?

Comment: What do you mean with web interface? Do you mean making the server return `null`? If that is the case, I don't control the server, the whole idea of the question is to be able to make requests that only consume the headers, but does not incur in the penalty of consuming the body over the network.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this?